# Why it is better to avoid returning lists in API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices

My question is about returning list in APIs.
suppose we have an API which returns a list of `Rating`.

and this is `Rating`:

```
public class Rating {

    private Long movieId;
    private Integer rating;
    .
    .
}
```

and this is a sample of the API's response:

```
[{"movieId":5870,"rating":5},{"movieId":1234,"rating":3}]
```

Ok. now I want to have an enhancement in my API and the enhancement is not to a particular object in the list. for example, I want to add a field which indicates who these `Rating`s belongs to.

but in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dmvhe2cw-_k) tutorial, the Instructor says:

> we cannot return the list anymore. we have to convert it into an
> object.

Why we cannot return a list anymore? we can have an API response like this:

```
[{"movieId":5870,"rating":5},{"movieId":1234,"rating":3},"John Doe"]
```

and it is its code:

```
@GetMapping("-sth-")
    public List<Object> foo() {

        List<Object> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        finalList.add(new Rating(5870L, 5));
        finalList.add(new Rating(1234L, 3));
        finalList.add("John Doe");

        return finalList;
    }
```

then why we don't do that? why he said we cannot return a list anymore? What is the problem in this new version of the API?
is it because we are returning a list of `Object`?

Comment: You can return any object that can get parsed into JSON, why not a list? Who is he? Maybe he wants the code to be more readable?

Comment: JSON clearly can represent what you want, so you *could* do something to that effect (no idea if your specific code will work), but the problem is that this kind of mixed-type list is tricky to parse in an automated way. Depending on the language/parsing/mapping framework it might mean a lot more work to get the data from the raw JSON into useful objects. It's just way less convenient to work with than properly-structured data.

Comment: I guess `List<Object>`,  `Object` is problem, not List; every thing (type include byte array) can add to list, how to parse it ? I add finalList.add("John Doe"); multi time in different order, when you receive JSON string , find "John Doe" in different position ,  what is meaning  of "John Doe",  finalList.add("John Doe");
        byte[] abc= new byte[] { (byte)0xee, 0x4e, (byte)0xd1, 0x21, (byte)0xe2, 0x32, 0x63, 0x13, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0xd4, 0x04, 0x05, 0x26, 0x37, 0x38, (byte)0x98 };
        finalList.add(abc); finalList.add("John Doe"); return finalList;

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74741483/java-map-with-lists-of-different-types-as-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tl;dr: it's good practice.

If you think of the API as a contract, I give you this information and you give me that information back, once you return a `List<Object>` you no longer have any way to reason about what is in that list and what you're supposed to do with it.

In the absence of "John Doe" in that list, you can tell a JSON parser to turn your response into a `List<Rating>` and it will without further assistance.
However, adding "John Doe" stops it from doing so, the best you can hope for is `List<Object>`. So now you are required to manually figure out where John Doe is in your list, whether he is there in the first place, etc.

You may need to write a custom parser or ensure that everyone using this API knows that John Doe may (or may not?) appear in last position, (or first, or anywhere in the middle?)
Frankly, it's **easier** on you as the developer to refactor into using a custom Object, so that you can tell your JSON library to parse the response into an Object of type `RatedActor`:

```
public class RatedActor {
    String name;
    List<Rating> ratings;
}
```

That's what OO languages are for (amongst other things) - to be able to present a fine-grained data model.
Now you, the compiler, and everybody else who may come into contact with your API and/or code knows clearly: The API returns a `RatedActor` with these properties. There is no 'hidden knowledge' embedded in a secret list. Otherwise you may as well scramble the API response with an Enigma machine and go "hey, figure that one out, API consumers!"

Answer (score 1):

It's more about best practices as using JSON Object are more compatible to changes in future. If we face any change in future we just need to add another entry (that is not part of collection but required along result like Status Code) as compared to changing the data type of list to object and breaking code. Returning JSON object makes program more flexible. You can return JSON List too if you want, there is no technical issue. Returning JSON objects also help you to send status code and description like (SUCCESS 500, ERROR 404) unlike JSON Array which does not give description of result.